# You are given the curve $y = 4x$, the $x$-axis, and $x=2$. Find the value of $x=b$ such that...

Tags: calculus

When given the curve $y = 4x$, the $x$-axis, and $x=2$. Find the value of $x=b$ such that...

$a)b$ divides the region between the curves into $two$ equal parts.

$b)$ When the region is rotated about the $x$-axis, $b$ will divide that area into $2$ equal volumes

I know there has to be an integral in respect to $x$ or $y$, but I can't seem to finalize it out.

Comment: Alright, so so far I tried setting the integral (ranging 0 to 4) at 4x (dx), which equaled 8 but I have no idea where to go from there or if that is even correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part a): The area of the region under the function $4x$ from $x=0$ to $x=b$ is equal to the area of the region from $x=b$ to $x=2$. We have
$$\int_0^b4x\, dx=\int_b^24x\, dx$$
Just evaluate the integrals in terms of $b$, then solve.

Part b): Since this is a solid of revolution, the volume is
$$\pi\int_a^b f(x)^2\,dx$$
which gives the equation
$$\pi\int_0^b (4x)^2\,dx=\pi\int_b^2 (4x)^2\,dx$$
Again, evaluate in terms of $b$, and solve.

Answer (score 0):

A) You want $x=b$ such that the area under $y=4x$ and above $y=0$ and between $x=0$ and $x=b$ is equal to the area under $y=4x$ and above $y=0$ and between $x=b$ and $x=2$.  I see based on your comment in the question that you're on the right track but not quite there.  As a hint, the integral representing the first area I mentioned is $\displaystyle \int_0^b 4x\, dx$.  Can you take it from here?

B)  I recommend using the disk method here (as opposed to the shell method, which will work but will be a little more tedious).  You have two regions that are being rotated around the $x$-axis.  Both regions are under $y=4x$ and above $y=0$.  The first region is between $x=0$ and $x=b$.  The second region is between $x=b$ and $x=2$.  Note that these are the same two regions as in part A above, although the value of $b$ will likely be different here.  As a hint, the integral representing the volume when the first region is rotated around the $x$-axis is $\displaystyle \pi\int_0^b (4x)^2 \, dx$.  Can you take it from here?